# How To Open Live Server In Atom?

Tags: atom-editor, liveserver

I switched my text editor from vs-code to atom and I'm not sure how to open Live Server.

Answer (score 2):

you can install live server from Atom Packages (install Packages on welcome page). There are several live server packages option available.
Once installed, each package provided its own documentation and features. Best way is then checking your live server settings in package panel.

Hope it helps, good luck with your journey on Atom